# "Error receiving broadcast Intent" in Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, broadcast

I receive this error:

```
04-17 09:35:10.227: E/AndroidRuntime(9377): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.aldakur.instalacionesdep.services.action.FIN flg=0x10 } in com.aldakur.instalacionesdep.info.RssAvisosFragment$ProgressReceiver@42721b68
04-17 09:35:10.227: E/AndroidRuntime(9377):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:776)
04-17 09:35:10.227: E/AndroidRuntime(9377):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-17 09:35:10.227: E/AndroidRuntime(9377):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-17 09:35:10.227: E/AndroidRuntime(9377):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-17 09:35:10.227: E/AndroidRuntime(9377):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
04-17 09:35:10.227: E/AndroidRuntime(9377):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 09:35:10.227: E/AndroidRuntime(9377):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-17 09:35:10.227: E/AndroidRuntime(9377):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
04-17 09:35:10.227: E/AndroidRuntime(9377):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
04-17 09:35:10.227: E/AndroidRuntime(9377):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-17 09:35:10.227: E/AndroidRuntime(9377): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-17 09:35:10.227: E/AndroidRuntime(9377):     at com.aldakur.instalacionesdep.info.RssAvisosFragment$ProgressReceiver.onReceive(RssAvisosFragment.java:123)
04-17 09:35:10.227: E/AndroidRuntime(9377):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:766)
```

This is my Fragment code.

`onCreateView` method:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rss_avisos, container, false);

    ListView lv = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.rss_avisos_lv);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    if(isMyServiceRunning()){

        pDialog3 = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog3.setMessage("3.Cargando Noticias...");
        pDialog3.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog3.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pDialog3.show();


        }

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(CheckNuevosAvisosIntentService.ACTION_PROGRESO);
        filter.addAction(CheckNuevosAvisosIntentService.ACTION_FIN);
        getActivity().registerReceiver(rcv, filter);
        AvisosEnListaAdapter adapter = new AvisosEnListaAdapter(getActivity(), avisosList);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}
```

And my `BroadCastReceiver`:

```
    public class ProgressReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    //ProgressDialog pDialog2 = new ProgressDialog(RssAvisosActivity.this);

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(intent.getAction().equals(CheckNuevosAvisosIntentService.ACTION_PROGRESO)) {
            int prog = intent.getIntExtra("progreso", 0);

            if(!pDialog3.isShowing()){
            pDialog3.setMessage("2.Cargando Noticias...");
            pDialog3.setCancelable(false);//erabiltzaileak atzera botoia sakatuz ez kantzelatzeko
            pDialog3.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDialog3.show();

            }

        }
        else if(intent.getAction().equals(CheckNuevosAvisosIntentService.ACTION_FIN)) {

            //Select
            DataBaseHelper myDB = new DataBaseHelper(getActivity().getBaseContext());
            myDB.openDataBase();
            avisosList = myDB.getAllAvisos("eu");
            AvisosEnListaAdapter adapter = new AvisosEnListaAdapter(getActivity(), avisosList);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

            if(pDialog3.isShowing()){
                pDialog3.dismiss();
        }
        }
    }

}
```

I think getActivity.unregisterReceiver (rcv) may be the solution
But do not know where to write.
In an activity, this code is written to the `onPause`.

Where to write same code for `Fragment` ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have a NullPointerException attempt at the line where you trying to `getActivity()`. So I think you are registering/unregistering receiver in the wrong way. You should register it at `onResume` and unregister at `onPause`, like this:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(CheckNuevosAvisosIntentService.ACTION_PROGRESO);
    filter.addAction(CheckNuevosAvisosIntentService.ACTION_FIN);
    getActivity().registerReceiver(rcv, filter);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(rcv);
}
```

Also, don't forget to remove this line `getActivity().registerReceiver(rcv, filter);` from `onCreateView()` method. And according to logcat exception appears when you are receiving `ACTION_FIN` action, so I highly recommend you to add `isAdded()` condition to your `if` clause to ensure that fragment is attached to activity:

```
    else if(intent.getAction().equals(CheckNuevosAvisosIntentService.ACTION_FIN) 
        && isAdded()) {
        // your code here
    }
```

Comment: But in a Fragment there are no methods onPause() and onResume().

Comment: Are you sure? check fragment lifecycle here http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating.

Comment: Did you add `isAdded()` condition ?

Comment: If you have a NPE at this `AvisosEnListaAdapter adapter = new AvisosEnListaAdapter(getActivity(), avisosList);` line, It seems that your avisosList is null or something in AvisosEnListAdapter constructor.

Comment: `AvisosList.size()` values is 245. Now app crashed in `lv.setAdapter(adapter);` After `AvisosEnListaAdapter adapter = new AvisosEnListaAdapter(getActivity(), avisosList);`

Comment: So It means that your listview is null

Comment: So, how to initialice it? i instanced it in onCreateView.   `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rss_avisos, container, false);  
  lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.rss_avisos_lv);`

Comment: According to this line `ListView lv = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.rss_avisos_lv);` you aren't keep reference to your listview, so you need to define it as a field of your Fragment, and then just instantiate it: `lv = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.rss_avisos_lv);`

Answer (score 1):

In most cases of using `BroadcastReceiver` in a `Fragment`, `BroadcastReceiver` is registered in `onStart` and unregistered in `onStop`. Where registering and unregistering a `BroadcastReceiver` is recommended of `onStart` and `onStop`. Because in the life span of a `Activity`, `onStart` is called after `onCreate` and `onStop` before `onDestroy` while usually widgets is initialized in `onCreate` but `onDestroy` can't be always executed in time. And the life span of a `Fragment` relies on that of a `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

Add line in `onReceive()` before you display dialog :

```
  @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {               
        if(intent.getAction().equals(CheckNuevosAvisosIntentService.ACTION_PROGRESO)) {
                int prog = intent.getIntExtra("progreso", 0);
                pDialog3 = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());    // this line will prevent NPE
                if(!pDialog3.isShowing()){
                    pDialog3.setMessage("2.Cargando Noticias...");
                    pDialog3.setCancelable(false);//erabiltzaileak atzera botoia sakatuz ez kantzelatzeko
                    pDialog3.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                    pDialog3.show();
                }
           }
```

It was getting `pDialog3` as NULL and throwing Null Pointer Exception